# Bash Completion

Tags: bash, tab-completion

I've tried to load [bash_completion](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/bash_completion) in my bash (3.2.25), it does not work. No message etc. I've used the following in my .bashrc

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_completion ]; then
  . ~/.bash_completion
fi
```

I also tried to use .bash_profile instead, but with the same result.
So the problem is why does it not work? Any idea? Hints?

Comment: Does it work if you type `source ~/.bash_completion` on the prompt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply sourcing that file will produce no output to the terminal. All it does is define a bunch of functions. Once you've sourced it, you should be able to do tab completions on svn commands. Type svn <kbd>Space</kbd>and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice. You should see a list of svn commands.

Comment: Oh my lord. I was running into the wrong direction. It works.

Answer (score 0):

So this may seem like a stupid question, but did you put the subversion bash_completion into a file called `.bash_completion` or into a file called `bash_completion` ?  (Note the initial dot)  What does `ls -la bash* .bash*` say?

For the snippet above to work, you need the subversion file to be in `.bash_completion`.  If it isn't, do:

```
mv -i bash_completion .bash_completion
```

Comment: I have put that into ".bash_completion" file. incl. the prefixing dot.